# Apple Appstore percent of downloads "stuck" / "not finishing" / "freezing"

Tags: ios, app-store

I work with a large(ish) app and every update we submit causes us to receive a handful of bad reviews regarding the app download "stuck", "not finishing", "freezing".

This has been happening since iOS 9 but it feels like its becoming increasingly more common.

Our users say the app is frozen, won't open, and can't be deleted or re-downloaded.

Some users have success after restarting the device. But some users swear its become impossible to remove the app.

I've contacted Apple in regards to this but haven't yet got a response.

Has anyone else been experiencing this trend? Is this something I've done incorrectly with my build causing these issues?

Any information is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you will need to debug your app (e.g. you could read the crash reports) – probably something is not correctly implemented; that must be an app-related issue, Apple probably won't help on you to resolve that.

Comment: There is no crash report. The app never is given the opportunity to open. The download doesn't finish.

Comment: how big is your app? if it is over 100MB, then your clients need WiFi to download it; otherwise the download will be suspended or not even started.